# Does honor affect the weather?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I saw a comment on a thread the other day that said something about how the worse your honor level is in Red Dead Redemption 2, the worse the weather. Is this true? I wouldn't have given this much credence normally, but I've noticed considerably more lightning and wind storms recently since my honor dropped quite a bit from robbing stores.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

I keep topping out the honour bar and I also get bad weather, lots of bad weather.

It seems as though the average weather conditions get worse the further you get through the game.

Buy Arthur a big hat and a big coat, he's going to need it.

Comment: I think you're probably right and this is a case of selective bias, or whatever the term is for something that you start to notice after someone points it out even though it was always there.